# rotate label to landscape in Interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, label, rotation, landscape

I just need help with interface builder. I am trying to rotate only a label for my apps but I can't find the rotate function any where..

Can anyone help me to rotate a label, do I need code in xcode to rotate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can rotate it in IB. You need to appy a transform to the view to get it to rotate.

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);
```

Comment: how do i do that... and does it rotate just label or the whole interface.. thanks

Comment: You can apply the transform to either a container view or a contained view. If container, then (I believe) should rotate all subviews within.

Comment: M_PI is defined in <math.h>, so... CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 4, add the following code to your View Controller:

```
@IBDesignable
class DesignableLabel: UILabel {
}

extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var rotation: Int {
        get {
            return 0
        } set {
            let radians = ((CGFloat.pi) * CGFloat(newValue) / CGFloat(180.0))
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in interface builder, change your label class type in the Identity Inspector to "DesignableLabel".  Your label should then be rotatable in interface builder.